# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined on Netlify CMS/React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, netlify, netlify-cms

### Environment

- Netlify CMS version: netlify-cms-app@2.12.17
- Git provider: git-gateway
- Browser version: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6)
  AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89
  Safari/537.36

### Explanation

As you can see below, the code works for the most part, but specifically in the CMS's Preview pane, when I add a `group` element (list), it breaks for some reason. I've noticed that this issue happens in the [custom preview template](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/customization/), in [this line](https://github.com/projectssome/testing/blob/9e148885db5be7f65a262d3cc59c99fc9b2ce268/src/components/templates/IndexPageTemplate.js#L12), but I wasn't able to see anything wrong in there. Is there a possible fix to it?

**When adding a `group` element**
[image]

**When adding a `subgroup` element (nested list)** - it works as expected
[image]

### Code

I created [this](https://github.com/projectssome/testing) public repo with just the code needed, so anyone can easily reproduce.
You can also see this site [here](https://loving-jang.netlify.app/).

**config.yml**

```
publish_mode: simple
slug:
  encoding: unicode
  clean_accents: false
  sanitize_replacement: "-"
backend:
  name: git-gateway
  branch: master
media_folder: static/images
public_folder: /images
collections:
  - name: pages
    label: Pages
    files:
      - file: src/pages/index.md
        label: Index
        name: index
        fields:
          - label: Groups
            name: groups
            widget: list
            fields:
              - label: Title
                name: title
                widget: string
              - label: Subgroups
                name: subgroups
                widget: list
                fields:
                  - label: Subtitle
                    name: subtitle
                    widget: string
    publish: true
    sortableFields:
      - commit_date
      - commit_author
    view_filters: []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `map` is failing when you add a new `Group` because the `subgroup` field is undefined.

For these kinds of issues with custom previews for netlify-cms, you have two options:

1. Add a `default` field on the `subgroup` widget in your `config.yml` (see [here](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/widgets#list)).
2. Or you can validate and/or fix the input `groups` object in `IndexPagePreview.js` before passing it through as a prop to your custom `IndexPagePreview`: `groups.forEach(g => g.subgroup = g.subgroup || [])`

Try them both, one might work better than the other for what you're doing with the data afterwards. :)

---

Update:

So I cloned your code, set up netlify etc etc. so I could get an exact solution working for your data-types.

**Solution 1:**
See the two new `default` keys below. If netlify CMS is given these, then it knows how to create the sub-objects for the list widget when you click on new. Otherwise it just goes for an empty string, which is normally fine, but as your preview was mapping sub-fields, it wasn't happy with this.

```
 fields:
 - {
    label: Groups,
    name: groups,
    widget: list,
    fields:
      [
        { label: Title, name: title, widget: string, default: ''},
        {
          label: Subgroups,
          name: subgroups,
          widget: list,
          default: [{ subtitle: '' }],
          fields:
            [{ label: Subtitle, name: subtitle, widget: string }],
        },
      ],
  }
```

**Solution 2:**
You need to instantiate the entire sub-object if it is empty, so it needs to be this just before you pass it in to the props.

```
groups.forEach(g => g.subgroups = g.subgroups || [{subtitle:''}])
```

After looking closer, doing it the "proper" way (Solution 1) seems better, as the CMS is actually creating the objects in a better way, and will save the objects in a properly-formatted way also. Solution 2 just fixes up the objects for the previewer, it doesn't have any effect on the saved files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Luke! I tried to apply both of your solutions, but it didn't seem to work (or I wasn't able to apply it right). The first one, when adding a new `Group`, returns another TypeError: `e.get is not a function`. The second one returned the same `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` TypeError, but now before I add a new `Group`. If it's not asking to much, could you provide an example, please?

Comment: Also this PR to fix your demo https://github.com/projectssome/testing/pull/1